# How do you sort your chats by contact name in WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

How can one alphabetically sort the contacts on the WhatsApp chat list? Right now, the list is completely random, making it difficult to locate a specific chat by its author (contact name)

Comment: Hi, it seems you accidentally created a duplicate account. Please refer to [the help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts and regain ownership of the question and reply to the comments on your post. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any way to sort them alphabetically in the chat list. Currently the Whatsapp chat list is by chat date, meaning the most recent ones will come up.

If you click on the bottom right green button you can access the contacts list, and those contacts are sorted alphabetically.
[image]

Comment: There is no such a thing as a bottom right green button I’m my chat window.

Comment: Sorry mate, I’ve added a screenshot for further clarity. Do note that this only accesses your Whatsapp contact list that is sorted alphabetically, and does not change the way your chat list is sorted permanently. Also, Aayush has posted a really great idea to use Whatsapp Business’s label feature, you should go check out his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp doesn't officially added this feature.. but if you really want to sort them then download Whatsapp business. You can use label to organize things..
Just like this.. (items are the people actually)

[image]

I too use whatsapp business and really love its auto reply function..